# for what : resemble in wordpress templates

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php 
    while ( $incomplete_custom_resources->have_posts() ) : 
        $incomplete_custom_resources->the_post();
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></td>
```

How to convert this code into pure PHP, What: this symbol resembles in WordPress or PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
while ( $incomplete_custom_resources->have_posts() ) {
  $incomplete_custom_resources->the_post();
}
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></td>
</tr>
...
```

Comment: how to echo after the get_the_title()

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer always has to explain how the problem is solved and what the problem is.